# ComboBox SelectedIndex changes automatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

In my client app, I've a `ComboBox` bound to a static list of items which server sends in `AcceptAsync` callback. When Client connects to the server for the first time, `ComboBox` gets populated and first item becomes the selected item. On disconnect, I've call for `Items.Clear()` on client side. Without doing anything, if I just connect, then disconnect and reconnect again: for the first time it selects the first item as expected BUT for the second time nothing is selected! When I click on combobox I can see all those items and select. Here's what I have in `xaml` for the combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static CC:ClientCode.Items}}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            SelectedValuePath="Id"
            SelectedIndex="0"
            SelectedValue="{Binding ItemCode}"/>
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure that ItemCode references a valid item. Do not set SelectedIndex when you have bound SelectedValue.

Comment: @Clemens, that's a notifiable `int`, isn't that `0` by default? It just has a `get` and `set` and at the end of `set` I've this `OnPropertyChanged()`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. ItemCode? If yes, it should hold a value that equals the Id property of one of the items in ClientCode.Items.

Comment: @Clemens, Yes, ItemCode, if i remove `SelectedIndex="0"` and initialize `ItemCode=1`, the behavior is exactly same!

Comment: And after reconnect, ItemCode references an existing item?

Comment: @Clemens, I don't have anything like `ItemCode = ClientCode.Items.First().Id;`, is it must?

Comment: Sure, how else should SelectedValue be valid?